# I'm a beginner at Flutter, how to repair this code?

Tags: debugging, flutter, dart

```
    import 'dart:math';

import 'package:dart_random_choice/dart_random_choice.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
```

I get random numbers here for my addition, subtraction, multiplication questions

```
int num1 = Random().nextInt(100); 
int num2 = Random().nextInt(100);

List<String> typeOfQuestions = [
  'Addition',
  'Subtraction',
  'Multiplication',
  'Division'
];

Widget question;
```

Here I create different types of widgets according to the math operation

```
Map questions = {
  "Addition": AdditionWidget(
    num1: num1,
    num2: num2,
  ),
  "Subtraction": SubtractionWidget(
    num1: num1,
    num2: num2,
  ),
  "Multiplication": MultiplicationWidget(
    num1: num1,
    num2: num2,
  )
};
```

gameWin tells whether the player pass the math and can proceed to next level

```
bool gameWin = false;

TextEditingController answerController;
```

initialize game is a function whenever a new game starts and choose a
random math equation

```
initializeGame() {
  String typeOfQuestion = randomChoice(typeOfQuestions);

  switch (typeOfQuestion) {
    case 'Addition':
      {
        question = questions['Addition'];
      }
      break;
    case 'Subtraction':
      {
        question = questions['Subtraction'];
      }
      break;
    case 'Multiplication':
      {
        question = questions['Addition'];
      }
      break;
    default:
      {
        question = questions['Subtraction'];
      }
      break;
  }
}

class Game extends StatefulWidget {
  _GameState createState() => _GameState();
}

class _GameState extends State<Game> {
```

I'm not sure whether I need initstate here, I just put it in case

```
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    initializeGame();

    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Math Rush'),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: Row(
            children: <Widget>[
              question,
              Flexible(
                child: TextField(
                  controller: answerController,
                  onChanged: (text) {
                    switch (question) {
                      case 'Addition':
                        {
                          if (num1 + num2 == int.parse(text)) {
                            gameWin = true;
                            checkAnswerIsCorrect();
                          }
                        }
                        break;

                        case 'Subtraction':
                        {
                          if (num1 - num2 == int.parse(text)) {
                            gameWin = true;
```

checkansweriscorrect actually means the answer is correct, as the
player wins this match, he can proceed to next level

```
                            checkAnswerIsCorrect();
                          }
                        }
                        break;
                        case 'Multiplication':
                        {
                          if (num1 * num2 == int.parse(text)) {
                            gameWin = true;
                            checkAnswerIsCorrect();
                          }
                        }
                    }
                  },
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  checkAnswerIsCorrect() {
    setState(
      () {
        if (gameWin == true) {
          num1 = Random().nextInt(100);
          num2 = Random().nextInt(100);
          initializeGame();
        }
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Its not clear what problem you are having. Your title needs to be made more clear. At the top just tell us what error you are seeing.

Comment: BTW, you're not using `Random` correctly.  You should instantiate *one* random number generator and repeatedly get random numbers from it, not instantiate *multiple* random number generators.

Comment: Can only second @TommieC. that the title should really be edited. But Random shouldnt be his main problem here ;-)